# Passing arguments to a command in Bash script with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, escaping

I'm trying to pass 2 arguments to a command and each argument contains spaces, I've tried escaping the spaces in the args, I've tried wrapping in single quotes, I've tried escaping \" but nothing will work.

Here's a simple example.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

ARG="/tmp/a b/1.txt"
ARG2="/tmp/a b/2.txt"

ARG_BOTH="\"$ARG\" \"$ARG2\""
cat $ARG_BOTH
```

I'm getting the following when it runs:

```
ARG_BOTH="$ARG $ARG2"
+ ARG_BOTH='/tmp/a\ b/1.txt /tmp/a\ b/2.txt'
cat $ARG_BOTH
+ cat '/tmp/a\' b/1.txt '/tmp/a\' b/2.txt
cat: /tmp/a\: No such file or directory
cat: b/1.txt: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/a\: No such file or directory
cat: b/2.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

#### TLDR

Put your args in an array and call your program as `myutil "${arr[@]}"`

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

file1="file with spaces 1"
file2="file with spaces 2"
echo "foo" > "$file1"
echo "bar" > "$file2"
arr=("$file1" "$file2")
cat "${arr[@]}"
```

#### Output

```
file1="file with spaces 1"
+ file1='file with spaces 1'
file2="file with spaces 2"
+ file2='file with spaces 2'
echo "foo" > "$file1"
+ echo foo
echo "bar" > "$file2"
+ echo bar
arr=("$file1" "$file2")
+ arr=("$file1" "$file2")
cat "${arr[@]}"
+ cat 'file with spaces 1' 'file with spaces 2'
foo
bar
```

Comment: Is there a solution for regular posix shells like dash?

Answer (score 6):

This might be a good use-case for the generic *"set"* command, which sets the top-level shell parameters to a word list. That is,  $1, $2, ... and so also $* and $@ get reset.

This gives you some of the advantages of arrays while also staying all-Posix-shell-compatible.

So:

```
set "arg with spaces" "another thing with spaces"
cat "$@"
```

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward *revision of your example shell script* that will work correctly is:

```
#! /bin/sh

ARG="/tmp/a b/1.txt"
ARG2="/tmp/a b/2.txt"

cat "$ARG" "$ARG2"
```

However, if you need to wrap up a whole bunch of arguments in one shell variable, you're up a creek; there is no portable, reliable way to do it.  (Arrays are Bash-specific; the only portable options are `set` and `eval`, both of which are asking for grief.)  I would consider a need for this as an indication that it was time to rewrite in a more powerful scripting language, e.g. Perl or Python.

Comment: Would you care to say why `set` could be a source of grief?

Comment: There's only one `"$@"`, so it can't be used for more than one thing at a time.  And `set -- $VARIABLE; cmd "$@"` does word splitting exactly the same way `cmd $VARIABLE` does, so that's no good.  And you have to make sure you aren't getting one of the many *other* things `set` does by accident.