# Making quotation marks survive to a command run inside a bash script

Tags: regex, bash

The following code saves `my_string` in the file `my_filename` and
then checks whether `pattern1` and `pattern2` are in the file. The
first is; the second isn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

my_string="One two three four" 
pattern1="two three"
pattern2="two four"

my_filename="my_temp_file"

safeGrepCommand() {
    typeset command_to_run="$*"
    typeset ret_code

    # echo command_to_run=$command_to_run
    eval $command_to_run
    ret_code=$?
    if [ $ret_code != 0 ]; then
        printf "Pattern %s is not in the file %s.\n" "${my_pattern}" "${my_filename}"
        exit $ret_code
    fi
}

echo $my_string > $my_filename

grep_command1="grep --quiet ${pattern1} ${my_filename}"
safeGrepCommand "$grep_command1"

grep_command2="grep --quiet ${pattern2} ${my_filename}"
safeGrepCommand "$grep_command2"

rm -f $my_filename
```

I am expecting to see the output

```
Pattern two four is not in the file my_temp_file.
```

Instead I see

```
grep: three: No such file or directory
grep: four: No such file or directory
```

As you'll see if you uncomment the echo line inside the function, the problem is that the quotation marks are not seen by grep.

```
command_to_run=grep --quiet two three my_temp_file
command_to_run=grep --quiet two four my_temp_file
```

How do I get bash to pass the quotation marks to grep? Alternatively, how do I specify "two three" as a regexp with [:space] and not worry about quotation marks.

Comment: Do not stick commands in strings. If you need to do this sort of thing use an array. You cannot get this to work reliably. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more details and discussion. In your case this is even simpler as you can just not use `grep_command1` at all and just pass the arguments to `safeGrepCommand` directly. (Though assigning `$*` to a variable will still bite you. Don't do that. Just use "$@" where you need the expansion (and you don't even need eval for that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving escapes in bash arguments $@](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820240/preserving-escapes-in-bash-arguments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to a command in Bash script with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753993/passing-arguments-to-a-command-in-bash-script-with-spaces)

Comment: I would suggest that using `eval` is the *opposite* of "safe"

Comment: @rici Indeed. I picked the one with the highest vote count I could find quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the pattern variable in double quotes as

```
grep_command1="grep --quiet \"${pattern1}\" \"${my_filename}\""
safeGrepCommand "$grep_command1"

grep_command2="grep --quiet \"${pattern2}\" \"${my_filename}\""
safeGrepCommand "$grep_command2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems something else is still wrong. If I replace "two<space>four" with "two<space><space>three" (i.e., with two spaces), I am expecting that the grep will fail. Yet after using the double quotes it succeeds. What is happening?

Comment: @Calaf its because the multiple spaces within double quotes are treated as a single space. If you want to force double space, escape the spaces as well. Which will work

Comment: @Calaf: this is not the way to go. Please see any of the answers using arrays in the linked duplicate questions, and/or read the bash faq http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 . (However, the problem is that you are not quoting the argument to `eval`.)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I had tried that, but instead of getting "Pattern two<space><space>three is not in the file my_temp_file." I got the two lines "Pattern two is not in the file my_temp_file.\nPattern three is not in the file my_temp_file."

Comment: @rici I tried to make the question as brief as possible. This seems like a trivial exercise. Still, my use of a function was intended only for safety. How would you write it?

Comment: @Calaf but in the script in question you havnt' set values for `my_pattern` or `my_filename`

Comment: @Calaf: what safety issue are you thinking of? It seems to me that your function is less safe. Put my response in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of resending arguments in a shell function:

```
doit_or_complain() {
  # The arguments are captured only to show how to do it. In practice,
  # I would just use "${@}" to run the command.
  local -a command=("$@")
  "${command[@]}"
  local rc=$?
  if ((rc)); then
    echo "The command failed" >> /dev/stderr
  fi
  return $rc
}
```

That will work with any random arguments:

```
doit_or_complain grep "a  b" "./my file with spaces in its name"
```

If you want to pass a complicated command to the shell function, you should use an array:

```
theCommand=(grep "a  b" "./my file with spaces in its name")
#...
doit_or_complain "${theCommand[@]}"
```

---

Note: The function in the OP used `exit $rc` if the command failed. That will exit the *current shell*, not just the function, which might be considered a tad unexpected, if not unsafe.