# Pass parameters that contain whitespaces via shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing, sh

I've got a program that I want to call by passing parameters from a shell variable. Throughout this question, I am going to assume that it is given by

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $#
```

i.e. that it prints out the number of arguments that are passed to it. Let's call it `count-args`.

I call my program like this:

```
X="arg1 arg2"
count-args $X
```

This works quite well. But now one of my arguments has a whitespace in it and I can't find a way to escape it, e.g. the following things do not work:

```
X="Hello\ World"
X="Hello\\ World"
X="'Hello World'"
```

In all of the cases, my program `count-args` prints out `2`. I want to find a way so I can pass the string `Hello World` and that it returns `1` instead. How?

Just for clarification: I do not want to pass all parameters as a single string, e.g.

```
X="Hello World"
count-args $X
```

should print out `2`. I want a way to pass parameters that contain whitespaces.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. ```X="Hello World"; count-args $X``` should print out ```1```. And to achieve this use quotes as show by user1934428: ```"$X"```. If you wish this to interpret this single string as multiple params, you're doing it wrong: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 !

Comment: @dekkard: As I have found a way to do exactly what I want, I am quite confident that my requirements are consistent. But thanks for that link, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array to store multiple, space-containing arguments.

```
$ args=("first one" "second one")
$ count-args "${args[@]}"
2
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with `xargs`. By replacing

```
count-args $X
```

with

```
echo $X | xargs count-args
```

I can use backslashes to escape whitespaces in `$X`, e.g.

```
X="Hello\\ World"
echo $X | xargs count-args
```

prints out 1 and

```
X="Hello World"
echo $X | xargs count-args
```

prints out 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
 count-args "$X"
```

The quotes ensure in bash, that the whole content of variable X is passed as a single parameter.

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't require any special handling of the *value* of `X`: `X="Hello World"` sets `X` to a string containing whitespace, and `count-args "$X"` calls the function with one argument. You also need to quote the expansion of `$1` inside the function to preserve the whitespace.

Comment: I think that this is not what I want. I do not want to pass all parameters as a single string. I want a way to pass parameters that contain whitespaces. Added a paragraph to my question. I hope that it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your Counting script:

```
$ cat ./params.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $#
```

For completeness here is what happens with various arguments:

```
$ ./params.sh
0
$ ./params.sh  1 2
2
$ ./params.sh
0
$ ./params.sh 1
1
$ ./params.sh 1 2
2
$ ./params.sh "1 2"
1
```

And here is what you get with variables:

```
$ XYZ="1 2" sh -c './params.sh $XYZ'
2
$ XYZ="1 2" sh -c './params.sh "$XYZ"'
1
```

Taking this a bit further:

```
$ cat params-printer.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Count: $#"
echo "1 : '$1'"
echo "2 : '$2'"
```

We get:

```
$ XYZ="1 2" sh -c './params-printer.sh "$XYZ"'
Count: 1
1 : '1 2'
2 : ''
```

This looks like what you wanted to do.

Now: If you have a script you cannot control and neither can you control the way the script is invoked. Then there is very little you can do to prevent a variable with spaces turning into multiple arguments.

There are quite a few questions around this on StackOverflow which indicate that you need the ability to control how the command is invoked else there is little you can do.

[Passing arguments with spaces between (bash) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094086/passing-arguments-with-spaces-between-bash-script)

[Passing a string with spaces as a function argument in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash)

[Passing arguments to a command in Bash script with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753993/passing-arguments-to-a-command-in-bash-script-with-spaces)

And wow! this *has* been asked so many times before:

[How to pass argument with spaces to a shell script function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151807/how-to-pass-argument-with-spaces-to-a-shell-script-function)