# How to properly pass a string with blanks as separate command line arguments?

Tags: bash

For example, if I want to rename the file `old_name` `new_name`, I can use the following code:

```sh
args='old_name new_name'
mv $args
```

However, if the original filename is `old name`, neither of the following code is able to work as intended:

```sh
args='"old name" new_name'
mv $args
# mv: target 'new_name' is not a directory
```

```sh
args='old\ name new_name'
mv $args
# mv: target 'new_name' is not a directory
```

`new_name` is recognized as the third arguments. It seems that characters like `"` and `\` lose their special meanings after expanded from a string.

How to properly pass a string with blanks as separate command line arguments? In this case, is there a way to specify that `old` and `name` should be grouped together?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Summary: you should use an array, as in `args=('old name' new_name)`, and then `mv "${args[@]}"`. There are many similar questions.

Comment: Like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129045/pass-parameters-that-contain-whitespaces-via-shell-variable

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminW. ! I wish I had found this, but I didn't come up with a good way to describe my question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays were added to the language precisely to address this use case (not as a general-purpose container):

```
args=("old name" "new name")
mv "${args[@]}"
```